# Using ViewHolder-pattern in a detail Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, master-detail

In my Android project I have an Activity that uses a Master-Detail view, created with two fragments.
My detailfragment is giving me some "problems" though.

It consists of 50+ controls (TextViews, EditTexts, CheckBoxes, Spinner). Of this 50+ controls I programmatically get a reference to 32 of these controls in my detail-fragment and load their data from my SQLite database.

When I run this and initialize my controls by using

```
(SomeControl).findViewById(R.id.mycontrol);
```

LogCat keeps warning me about that I might be doing too much on the main thread.

I know that findViewById and inflating views is an expensive operation, so I had an idea!

I was wondering if there was some way to use the viewholder pattern or view-recycling on my detail-fragment like I'm doing on my ListFragment. that way I could avoid reinitializing my detailview each time I select another item in my ListView. And avoid calling .findViewById as much as I do. Does anyone have an idea on how to implement something like this. Would it make any difference if I did initialization of the controls in the onCreate-method of my detailsfragment? I was also thinking about making my detailsfragment a "singleton" and then just use getLoaderManager().restartLoader when the selection of my listfragment changes. Any thoughts on all of this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you're talking about `Choreographer` warnings, I personally ignore them. I've seen discussions about this before but never a definitive answer as to what they really mean or if they're actually indicating anything truly detrimental.

Comment: Choreographer warnings is exactly what I'm talking about. So I should not be worried about these then?

Comment: Well as I said, I've never seen a good explanation of what the warnings mean although obviously they're triggered by complex view generation or data handling. Also I see them on some devices and not others but my app never causes an ANR popup so basically I consider them as low priority. At some point I'll look more closely and see if I can make my code a bit more streamlined in certain places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Had to change my implementation entirely though.

Now my implementation is using loaders on both ListFragment and DetailFragment.

Here's a list of changes I've made:

1. Created a interface for my ListFragment with one method (onSomethingClicked(SomeObject obj)) and made ListFragment observable through this interface.
2. Implemented the interface in my DetailFragment and registered a listener on the ListFragment.
3. Implemented the method onSomethingClicked() in DetailFragment. When this is triggered i pass data from ListFragment to DetailFragment and restart my DetailFragment-loader and load data into my already initialized controls in OnLoadFinished.

No need to inflate the view every time the selection in the list changes and no need to .findViewById's AND MOST IMPORTANTLY no more Choreographer warnings :)

Comment: Just a heads up. One `Fragment` should never communicate directly with another - it goes against the design model of `Fragments`. The idea of a `Fragment` is that it should be modular, self-contained and reusable. By all means use interfaces but implement them as callbacks in the `Activity` which contains the two `Fragments`. At some point in future you may want to reuse one of the `Fragments` on their own or even with a different `Fragment`. In that way, direct communication will break.

Comment: I know. But this would again lead to having to inflate and initialize the controls for every ListClick, which I was trying to avoid.
Like in code shown here:
[link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Then I would have to use: 
FragmentTransaction transaction = ...
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);

Comment: Sorry but I don't see your logic on the comment above. If you can communicate between fragments with FragmentA <-> FragmentB approach then what's the difference to FragmentA <-> Activity <-> FragmentB. An Activity can call public methods in any Fragment it is hosting without having to replace it with a FragmentTransaction.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. You are of course correct. When talking about activity callbacks I just thought it as in google's fragment example, but of course you could also go through the activity, which would actually be best-practice. I better rework my code a little more.

Comment: No problem - perhaps my first comment wasn't clear. Using an `Activity` which 'knows' what `Fragments` it's using (and controlling how they interact) and having `Fragments` which don't need to 'know' about each other is definitely a better OOD approach. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well unless you're using the exact same layout for each control then I'm not sure if there's a way to do that.

But there may be a way to solve your problem: using an AsyncTask.

As long as those controls aren't necessary for your program to crunch data (and from your explanation I don't think the UI elements would be triggered until the user has interacted with it) you should be fine and the main thread will be free to do whatever it needs. The only downside I see with this method would be that some UI elements might appear maybe a half a second late (not so bad if you think about it).

Comment: I had thought of doing the same. My problem with this solution is it would still require the work to be done each time and would be a waste of CPU cycles without any performance gain. The layout is always the same and also the controls.